# Porque la sintaxis para indicar que un parametro de una clase generica es comparable es <T extends Comparable<T>>?

Tags: java, comparaciones, interface, genericos

He estado mirando diferentes posts sobre la misma pregunta pero no entiendo porque en la sintaxis `<T extends Comparable<T>>` se pone la palabra `extends` y no la palabra `implements`, si `Comparable` es una interfaz, el argumento de la clase genérica no debería de implementar la interfaz `Comparable` en vez de extenderla? por ejemplo si tengo una interfaz `A` y una clase normal `B`, si intento escribir en la definición de la clase `B`, `B extends A` tendré un error de compilación porque `A` no es una clase sino que es una interfaz y debería cambiar `extends` por `implements`, porque en este caso hay ese problema de compilación pero al poner que el parametro `T` tiene que ampliar la interfaz `Comparable<T>` no hay ningún problema?

PD: Es mas, si se escribe `<T implements Comparable<T>>`tendré un error de compilación.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Porque no significa lo mismo que en la definición de una clase.

Al ver cualquier *keyword* hay que tener en cuenta que **el contexto es importante**. Muchos *keywords* tienen significados diferentes según donde se apliquen.

Por ejemplo, `final` en una clase indica que no se puede heredar de esa clase; en un método que una subclase no puede redefinir el método y en una variable que no se puede modificar su valor. Aunque en los tres casos se puede ver una cierta "afinidad semántica" del *keyword* con su uso, son tres casos bien definidos.

Así, cuando tienes

```
public class MiThread<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Thread {
```

Los dos `extends` son distintos

- `extends Thread` indica que `MiThread` cumplirá el contrato de `Thread` **y heredará la implementación de sus métodos**. Aquí definimos la clase, así que es importante saber de donde se obtienen los métodos<sup>1</sup>
- `<T extends Comparable<T>>` solo significa que `T` cumplirá el contrato de `Comparable<T>`. Si eso lo hace heredando la implementación o implementando sus métodos, *es algo interno a la implementación de T*. A `MiThread` solo le interesa saber que, debido a esta definición, puede hacer

  ```
  public void miFuncion(T t1, T t2) {
     if (t1.compare(t2)) {
        ...
  ```

  y como funcionará el `compare`

De hecho, este último *extends* es solo un parte de lo que se denomina *[bounded types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)* (tipos limitados) y que incluye varias opciones que no están disponibles o funcionan de forma diferente que en el primer *extends*:

- múltiples `extends`. Al definir la clase solo se puede extender de una superclase. Aquí eso no es necesario (por los motivos ya explicados arriba):

  ```
  <T extends Comparable<T> & Serializable & Number>
  ```
- wildcards con límite superior:

  ```
  <? extends Serializable> --> "Cualquier objeto que extienda/implemente Serializable, pero sin saber cuál es su clase"
  ```
- wildcards con límite inferior (nótese que aquí también se reutiliza `super` con otro significado):

  ```
  <? super Integer> --> "Cualquier objeto de una de las superclases de `Integer`"
  ```

**TL;DR** Aunque los dos `extends` implican significados similares, se usan para representar cosas diferentes. La gente de Sun podría haber perfectamente haber decidido usar otro *keyword* `<T supercalifragilísticoespialidoso Serializable>`, y todo funcionaría igual. Sin embargo, decidieron usar `extends` porque el sentido es más fácil de identificar.

---

<sup>1</sup>Se podría decir que se podría haber hecho que todas las superclases e interfaces se definieran mediante `extends` y que el compilador diera un error si había más de una clase. Sin embargo:

- hace más visible la diferencia entre clases e interfaces.
- esto se hizo así ya desde la primera versión de Java en que el compilador era mucho más básico.

Comment: Explicaciones como esta son las que se agradecen. Al menos a mí me valen mucho.